Troubleshooting Error in 2D CNN Object Detection: 'Found 0 Images Belonging to 0 Classes'
I'm new to computer vision and would like to use 2D CNN for object detection. However, I'm encountering an error during training that says 'Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.' Can someone explain the structure of the dataset and provide guidance on the necessary preparations, such as bounding boxes and images?
i prepared my dataset on 2 folders one for images and the other one for annotations (bbox .txt) i tried to make each image has it own file and i started the training but it not working

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
